# how can i add this two python scripts together?

Tags: python

so i have this python script which looks like this:

```
New_folder = "C:\Songs"

arr_txt = [x for x in os.listdir(New_folder) if x.endswith(".mp3")]

testfile = [New_folder]

for i in range(len(testfile)):

for x in testfile:

    print(*arr_txt, sep="\n")

    print()
```

which reads all the names of the files in my directory.

and the second part i want to add is a letter converter which it's script looks like:

```
from unidecode import unidecode
s = ""  #the script in there <---
s = unidecode(s)
print(s)
```

so I want the second part to connect with the first script and whatever result is coming out of the first script to go into the second script so that it gets converted

Comment: Make the first script a function. Then call it from the second script

Comment: @sshashank124 and how would that look like? sorry i am still a beginner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilise functions in Python.

In one file, let's call this `extract.py`, you should specify the pre-defined method for other scripts to use, e.g.

```py
# extract.py

def get_file_names():
  New_folder = "C:\Songs"
  arr_txt = [x for x in os.listdir(New_folder) if x.endswith(".mp3")]
  return arr_txt # this is important for caller to process the extracted value
```

And then in another file, let's say `process.py`, you call the method you want to use from `extract.py`. This can be done using `import`

```py
# process.py
from extract import get_file_names
from unidecode import unidecode

s = get_file_names()
for file_name in s:
  print(unidecode(filename))
```

This solution should work for using the latest Python interpreter. Please do note that `import` works slightly different in Python 2.x.

Comment: what  do i  if i cant download a package

Comment: please look for question on this site such as "how to find python package" or "how to install python packages". there are already tons of similar answered question that may also answer yours. it is very much appreciated that you do this before posting duplicates of question and it is very practical too. happy stackoverflow-ing :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like below

```
from unidecode import unidecode
def playmusic():
    New_folder = "C:\Songs"
    arr_txt = [x for x in os.listdir(New_folder) if x.endswith(".mp3")]
    testfile = [New_folder]
    for i in range(len(testfile)):
        for x in testfile:
            print(*arr_txt, sep="\n")
            print()
playmusic()
s = ""
s = unidecode(s)
print(s)
```

Comment: it did not work

Comment: What exactly you want there , because your first script is not returning anything , do you want to print the unicode of value of "x" from "for x in testfile"